# How to Use the GSL Library in an R Package?

Tags: r, gsl

I'm trying to build an R package which needs to be portable (i.e. be able to install on other machines).  I am building the package with some C code (called using `.C()`), and I use the gsl library.

When I try to build the package using `R CMD BUILD`, I get an error saying that the package or namespace failed to load since it was unable to load the shared object.  Below I have made a simple toy example to reproduce the error I'm getting.

myran.R file:

```
myran <- function(){
  a <- 1.1
  nothing <- .C("myran",as.double(a))
  return(nothing[[1]])
}
```

myran.C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

void myran(double * a){
  const gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
  unsigned long int theseed;
  theseed = time(NULL);
  gsl_rng_set(r,theseed);
  *a = gsl_ran_flat(r,0,1);
}
```

NAMESPACE file:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
useDynLib(myran)
export(myran)
```

I then run `R CMD BUILD myran` and get the following output:

```
* checking for file ‘myran/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘myran’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to process help pages
      -----------------------------------
* installing *source* package ‘myran’ ...
** libs
/usr/bin/cc -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/local/include   -fPIC  -pipe -Os -m64  -c myran.c -o myran.o
/usr/bin/cc -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o myran.so myran.o -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘myran’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran/libs/myran.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran/libs/myran.so, 6): Symbol not found: _gsl_rng_mt19937
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran/libs/myran.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran/libs/myran.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/private/var/folders/8y/f4_br32s1xn2d3rq2pswrtyr0000gw/T/RtmpIBvMbd/Rinst93381cca4b71/myran’
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
```

What do I need to change to make this package build properly in such a way that it is portable and can be installed on other machines?

Comment: Two suggestions: i) Look for package with 'gsl' in the name or description among the list of R packages; they are many. See how they do it.  ii) Don't use `.C()`, use `.Call()`.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Just becaus you use a library written in C does not justify the C tag (otherwise tat tag would be allowed everywhere).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Why do you recommend `.Call()` instead of `.C()`?  I get a segmentation fault when I use `.Call()` but I don't when I use `.C()` when I use the shared object `myran.so` from `R CMD SHLIB`.

Comment: No experienced R user recommends `.C()`, it is too restrictive, I would look at _existing_ packages. My RcppGSL package includes a whole GSL-using example package. My RcppZiggurat package also uses the GSL RNGs.